# GraphQL - return products with pair of availabilities, not alone

Tags: graphql

I need to return a list of products where each product can have few availabilities. I need to return products where there is not availability X but can be returned if product has availability X and Y. All I did is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "product_availability_id": [
              "X"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How I can add a condition to return products if they have product_availability_id "X", "Y"